# How to pass argument in class that extends "EditorPart" from handler class to affect "createPartControl" UI creation

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have 2 problems.

1) Command handler not responding for EditorPart

2) How to pass argument to a class that extends "EditorPart" to affect "createPartControl" method for UI creation.

Please have a look below in my code for better understanding. I have created command handler for Editor but my handler is not responding as expected. I want to have the selected file path in the **package explorer** and pass this file path value to the class that extends EditorPart in order to create UI based on this selected file.

**Handler.java**

```java
    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
         // get the page
         IWorkbenchWindow window = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindow(event); 
         IWorkbenchPage page = window.getActivePage();
         // get the selection
         ISelection selection = HandlerUtil.getCurrentSelection(event);
         IStructuredSelection sel = (IStructuredSelection) selection;
         Object selObj = sel.getFirstElement();

         if (selObj instanceof IResource) {
        resource = (IResource) selObj;
        project = resource.getProject();
        location = project.getLocation();
    }else { 
        IAdaptable adaptable = (IAdaptable)selObj;
        Object adapter = adaptable.getAdapter(IResource.class);
        resource = (IResource) adapter;
        project = resource.getProject();
        location = project.getLocation();   
    }

    TaskEditorInput input = new TaskEditorInput();
    try {
            page.openEditor(input, "launcher.ChartEditor");
        } catch (PartInitException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return null;
}
```

**class that extends EditorPart**

```java
    @Override
    public void init(IEditorSite site, IEditorInput input) throws PartInitException {
    setSite(site);
    setInput(input);
    setPartName("ChartEditor"); 
    }

    public void createPartControl(Composite _parent) {

    }

    public void createChart(String filePath) {
          dataset = chart1.createDataset(filePath);
          try {
              chart = chart1.createChart(dataset);
              frame = new ChartComposite(parent, SWT.NONE, chart, true);
              frame.pack();
          } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
    }
```

I want pass the value of selected filepath in this createChart(String filePath) method from handler class. How can i do this? Please help me.

Comment: Is `TaskEditorInput` a class you created? You can pass values in the editor input.

Comment: Yes. This class implements IEditorInput

Comment: But for that i need a working command handler that retrieve the selected filepath from package explorer and then i can try to pass this filepath through editor input

Comment: Please don't ask multiple unrelated questions in one question - it makes it very hard to answer. What **exactly** is not working in the code to get the selection?

Comment: I am not getting the file path which is selected in package explorer.

Comment: You probably need to use the platform adapter manager (see updated answer) but it is hard to say when you don' tell us exactly what part of the code is not working.

Comment: Actually what i find is my code is not even getting into handler part. I have checked it through printing a message but the message does not print. I am pressing Open With in editor but the handler is not responding for the command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the value you want to pass to your class implementing `IEditorInput` (`TaskEditorInput` in your case). The editor input is given to the editor `init` method so you can get the value there:

```java
@Override
public void init(IEditorSite site, IEditorInput input) throws PartInitException {

  if (input instanceof TaskEditorInout) {
     TaskEditorInput taskInput = (TaskEditorInput)input;

     // TODO save value for createPartControl
  } 

  setSite(site);
  setInput(input);
  setPartName("ChartEditor"); 
}
```

To be sure to get the resource corresponding to a selection you need to use the platform adapter manager. On modern versions of Eclipse you can use

```java
IStructuredSelection sel = HandlerUtil.getCurrentStructuredSelection(event);

IResource resource = Adapters.adapt(sel.getFirstElement(), IResource.class);
```